# What is wrong with my calculated field's logic (trying to compute percentage)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, math, stored-procedures, percentage

My TSQL to calculate percentage is apparently goofed up; this is part of my Stored Procedure logic:

```
. . .
AVG(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) 
Week1Price,
    AVG(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) 
Week2Price,
    AVG(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) 
 -
    AVG(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) 
PriceVariance,
    AVG(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) 
 -
    AVG(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) 
    / 
NULLIF(AVG(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END),0) 
PercentageOfPriceVariance
. . .
```

What I want to do with PercentageOfPriceVariance is:

```
(Week2Price - Week1Price) / Week1Price
```

e.g., if Week2Price is 3.38, and Week1Price is 20.27, then (Week2Price - Week1Price) should be -16.89; and then that (-16.89) divided by 3.38 should be -4.99.

Note, though, that the results I am getting differ wildly from that (see row 3, where the % is 2.38):

[image]

What is wrong with the logic in my calculated field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parenthesis should apply for the first set ie., `(Week2Price - Week1Price)` other wise the division operation `Week1Price / Week2Price` will execute first the minus operation after that. That is the reason the result is differ from your expectation.

See the example:

```
SELECT (3.38 - 20.27) / NULLIF(3.38, 0) -- result -4.997041
SELECT 3.38 - 20.27 / NULLIF(3.38, 0)   -- result -2.617041
```

So you need to apply the parenthesis for the first set will solve the problem.

**Note:** In your actual code the divisor section contains the `WeeK1Price` only, but in the post you mentioned the data need to divide by `Week2Price`.

Currently your code returns the wrong data due to the wrong divisor.

```
SELECT 3.38 - 20.27 / NULLIF(20.27, 0)  -- result 2.3800000
```

So your actual code should be:

```
(
 AVG(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) 
-
 AVG(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END)
) 
/ 
NULLIF(AVG(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END), 0) 
PercentageOfPriceVariance
```